# Printing rectangle from instance method

Tags: printing

I am having trouble with an instance method that uses a nested for loop to print a rectangle of asterisks.  When the code is executed, once it hits the print method the output in the console disappears and the program continues running.

public class Rectangle {

```
private int length;
private int width;

//Constructor for a rectangle with no parameters
public Rectangle() {

    //create a square rectangle with length of 1
    length = 1;
    width = 1;
```

}//End Rectangle0

```
//Constructor for a rectangle with 2 parameters
public Rectangle(int len, int wid) {

    //create a rectangle with given parameters
    length = len;
    width = wid;

}//end Rectangle2

//method to print rectangle
public void print() {

    //loop to print rectangle
    for(int i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= width; i++) {

            System.out.print("*");//prints row

        }//end nested for loop

        System.out.println();//begin new line

    }//end for loop
}//End method print
```

}//End class rectangle

If the length = 3 and width = 4, output should be three rows of asterisks all with 4 columns of asterisks

Instead of that result, once it begins to print the rectangle, all output disappears from the console and the program does not stop running.

Comment: Both of your loops increment i (i++). Can you try changing the inner loop to j++?

Comment: That fixed it, I can 't believe I missed that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing 'i' in the inner j loop, Change that to j++.
Also since you are using i <= length so start the loop from i=1 instead of i=0. Same for inner j loop.
Hope this helps.